# Is there some way a user with an asterisk as password in /etc/shadow but a correct login shell in /etc/passwd would be able to login via SSH?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, password, user-management

Let's assume the following. We have a server which is accessible via SSH. There is an user in `/etc/passwd` who has a valid login shell (so for example `/bin/bash`, instead of an invalid one like `/bin/false`).

This user has an asterisk (`*`) in the second (password) field of `/etc/shadow`. Is there some way that this user could login via SSH if he doesn't have a ssh key in his `~/.ssh/` folder?

Or, to rephrase the question somewhat: What would be the reason for many online guides to recommend to disable the login shell, when there is a `*` in the password field of `/etc/shadow`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `*` in the location of the hashed password in `/etc/shadow` effectively disables all password based logins as no user input will ever result in a hash value of `*`. But the user can still login with his/her ssh keys.

Comparing to `*` the exclamation mark `!` is not only an illegal hash but it also [traditionally indicates](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/shadow.5.html) a *locked account*. OpenSSH in the Portable variant (which is what you have on GNU/Linux) [honors](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/4403b62f5548e91389cb3339d26a9d0c4bb07b34/auth.c#L112) [locking](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/2923d026e55998133c0f6e5186dca2a3c0fa5ff5/platform.c#L228) by `!` but only when **not** using PAM (`UsePAM no`). Linux PAM's `pam_unix` module [treats](https://github.com/linux-pam/linux-pam/blob/bcba17939e1b1a568cd4a764534cde74d37078cc/modules/pam_unix/passverify.c#L87) `*` and `!` the same way.

Note that different UNIX-like platforms may use another string to lock an account.

The reason to set an invalid shell is simply to prevent interactive login sessions from working (regardless of whether of not a password for the account is set) and will block `sudo su - user` and similar from working.